# ElasticSearch Typescript Support

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

I’m really new to ElasticSearch (picked it up a week ago). I’m trying to integrate it into one of my NodeJS applications. I’m using the guide [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/typescript.html) to implement it using Typescript.

From this page, it is saying I should define my own object interfaces to be used so that operations do not have a return type of `any`.

I want to ask how exactly I’m supposed to go about doing this? Do I need to define an interface for request body, response, and source for each document type I use in my implementation?

Like, do I need separate interfaces for doing `match`, `multi_match`, etc... queries, Responses, and Sources? Or is there a way to define a generic interface to work with all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success using the DefinitelyTyped [ElasticSearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/elasticsearch) library.

I'd suggest leveraging those types, and then adding your own definitions for whatever you store (which will be returned to you from ElasticSearch in the `_source` object.

Comment: Ah. That’s actually better. Lol. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still the best solution in 2022

Comment: hey! I should update this answer. Definitely Typed is still pretty good, but Elastic has released their own typescript library which is also very good: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/typescript.html